# Lit element object property is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, object, lit

I have a react component that gets a list of items (objects). When I pass it to child - which is a Lit Element. It'ss coming back as undefined.

I had made sure the data is coming back. Also tried hardcoding an array of objects. Still no luck.

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

I can’t seem to figure out why it's showing as defined. When I pass in a single value from the object it works, but when the whole object is passed down to the child it's undefined.

React js Parent component:

```
const ListExample = () => {
  const [pokemons, setPokemons] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getPokemons().then((response) => {
      setPokemons(response.data.pokemons);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {pokemons.map((item, i) => (
        <poke-card key={item.id} item={item}></poke-card>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ListExample;
```

Child - Lit Element

```
import { LitElement, html, css } from "lit-element";

class PokemonCard extends LitElement {
  static styles = css`
    .card {
      background: white;
      border-radius: 1rem;
      padding: 2rem;
      box-shadow: 4px 4px 12px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
      height: 500px;
      transition: 0.2s;
    }
    .card:hover,
    .card:focus-within {
      transform: translateY(-5rem);
    }
  `;

  static get properties() {
    return {
      item: { type: Object }
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { item } = this;

    return html`
      <div>
        <p>${item.name}</p>
      </div>
    `;
  }
}

customElements.get("poke-card") ||
  customElements.define("poke-card", PokemonCard);
```

Comment: @zx01 the child is not react, its Lit Framework. It doesn't have props.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting item to equal all the entire props you're passing into it.
Just refer to the name directly.

```
<p>${this.props.item.name}</p>
```

Comment: That is not the case. Please read my question again. I am using Lit element for my child component. I am destructing the prop. But I did try what you said and still same error

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I had to JSON stringify the object for lit element to pick it up.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer to this question would be fixed by [RFC: Plan for custom element attributes/properties in React 19](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11347)

The following is the relevant excerpt from the RFC and current workaround, until React ships improved attribute/property support.

> When React tries to pass data to a custom element it always does so using HTML attributes.
>
> `<x-foo bar={baz}> // same as setAttribute('bar', baz)`
>
> Because attributes must be serialized to strings, this approach creates problems when the data being passed is an object or array. In that scenario, we end up with something like:
>
> `<x-foo bar="[object Object]">`

This is the issue you've hit. One possible solution is to JSON stringify your object/array to pass it via the attribute. However this has some performance cost. A workaround that doesn't require serializing/parsing JSON allows setting the array/object directly:

> ... using a `ref` to manually set the property.
>
> `<x-foo ref={el => el.bar = baz}>`